# POST Javascript array to MVC controller .NET 5.0

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

im trying to send some data from my javascript array to my mvc controller.
When i debug through im ending in my method `public void GetJSArray(List<SelectorModel> selectorModels)`

but `selectorModels` is `null`.

Here is my model.

```
public class SelectorModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Cords { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my C# code in controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void GetJSArray(List<SelectorModel> selectorModels)
        {
            //Code here           
        }
```

and here is my JavaScript/Ajax

```
function SaveInfoSpots() {
    var savedeSpots = JSON.stringify({ selectorModels: infospots });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/GetJSArray',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON',//json
        data: savedeSpots,
        traditional: true
    });
}
```

If i make a `console.log(savedeSpots)` i get this.
`{"selectorModels":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Infospot1","Cords":"5000.00, 2293.85, 2278.05"},{"ID":1,"Name":"Infospot2","Cords":"1.94, 584.50, 5000.00"},{"ID":1,"Name":"Infospot3","Cords":"5000.00, -2705.97, -277.02"},{"ID":1,"Name":"Infospot4","Cords":"5000.00, 504.93, -2845.93"}]}`

Comment: Have you tried adding `[FromBody]` to the param in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two place need modify in your code:

First, about [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0), add [FromBody] attribute on action parameter:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void GetJSArray([FromBody]List<SelectorModel> selectorModels)
{
    //Code here           
}
```

Second, your API need an array not an object, so when you call the API, you need post the parameter like this:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Infospot1",
        "Cords": "5000.00, 2293.85, 2278.05"
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Infospot2",
        "Cords": "1.94, 584.50, 5000.00"
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Infospot3",
        "Cords": "5000.00, -2705.97, -277.02"
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Infospot4",
        "Cords": "5000.00, 504.93, -2845.93"
    }
]
```

not the `{"selectorModels":...}` format.

If you just need APIs, create webapi project is better than mvc project.

Comment: Thanks :-) i added `[FromBody]` and removed `{"selectorModels":...}`. now im getting the data in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[FromBody]` to your controller list param such as

```
public void GetJSArray([FromBody] List<SelectorModel> selectorModels)
```

Try removing

```
traditional: true
```

and

```
 charset=utf-8
```

from the `ajax` call as well. Should see the populated list then in the controller.